Speeding up CI on GitHub for vcpkg
We are working on a C++ project and using vcpkg for dependency management.
We’re facing an issue where the CI process takes too long, although the runner is good enough (at least better than my PC, which can build everything much faster).
we define the following steps in the build.yml file:

actions/checkout
Install vcpkg
Install dependencies from vcpkg.json (*)
Configure with CMake (*)
Build
Test

The steps of installing dependencies and configuring with cMake each take around 5 minutes, and it is very annoying to wait for 3 or 4 queued actions more than an hour till yours is tested, as we have only one self-hosted runner.
I have tried using a binary caching solution for vcpkg, but it doesn’t seem to make a difference.
Has anyone faced the same problem or has suggestions on how to optimize this process?
EDIT: build.yml file
name:
on:
  workflow_call:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: CMake
        uses: jwlawson/actions-setup-cmake@v1.14
        with:
          cmake-version: '3.27.1'

      # Binary Cache Setup
      - name: Export GitHub Actions cache environment variables
        uses: actions/github-script@v7
        with:
          script: |
            core.exportVariable('ACTIONS_CACHE_URL', process.env.ACTIONS_CACHE_URL || '');
            core.exportVariable('ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN', process.env.ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN || '');

      #Set vcpkg binary sources to use GitHub Actions cache
      - name: Set vcpkg binary sources
        run: |
          echo "VCPKG_BINARY_SOURCES=clear;x-gha,readwrite" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Install vcpkg
        uses: lukka/run-vcpkg@v11

      - name: Install dependencies from vcpkg.json
        run: vcpkg install --triplet x64-linux

      - name: Configure with CMake
        run: cmake -B ${{ vars.SHARED_BUILD_DIR }}/${{ github.run_id }} -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DENABLE_CUDA=ON -DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc

      - name: Build
        run: cmake --build ${{ vars.SHARED_BUILD_DIR }}/${{ github.run_id }} --parallel

      - name: Test
        run: ctest -C Release --output-on-failure --test-dir ${{ vars.SHARED_BUILD_DIR }}/${{ github.run_id }}

as I mentioned I tried the solution on Microsoft website. and modified build.yml a lot of times, but in vain.

Are you able to share the build.yml file text?

edited! I added the yml file to the post

Have you verified the binary caching is actually working? IE does the install step fully run each time?

@jpr42 yes, I can see in the cache tab, that some packages have been cached, and in the step of installing (Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Restored 15 package(s) from GitHub Actions Cache in 4.1 min. Use --debug to see more details.). However the process takes nearly the the same time
